# How to suspend cordova app from running in the background ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, phonegap

I've got a cordova app which has to do with many timers. Basically they just count from let say 100 to 0 and play a sound at the end. I've realised that they don't stop counting when my app is moved to the background (i.e. by pressing the home button). On Android I solved it by setting "keepRunning" preference in config.xml to false.

```
<preference name="keepRunning" value="false" />
```

The thing is I can't stop it from running in the background on my ios devices (Simulators to be specific). All articles and posts that I found are about how to keep it running but what I need is actually the opposite. I don't what the app to close as well. Just to pause it. I thought about using "onPause()" function but I don't really know what to write in there. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the default on an actual device is paused which is why you find the opposite in your search. Try it on a real device.

Comment: I don't have one :/